# libGdx - different fonts for cyrillic and latin characters

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx

There is a problem. String may contains latin and cyrillic characters. For latin characters i want use "Custom Font", and for cyrillic - "Helvetica". How i can do this with freeType generator for libGdx?

PS: it must be like font-family rule in CSS

```
    font-family: 'Custom Font', Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Comment: Does your `String` have Cyrillic and Latin characters at the same time? If not, your code can decide at runtime what font to use.

Comment: Yes. `String` may have Cyrillic and Latin characters at the same time

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to modify the `FreetypeFontGenerator` somehow. 
   Or you can post an issue to github.
2. Modify or merge the font file(ttf) using software such as FontForge.